# ClickOnce Prerequisites 4.5.2 prompting users to upgrade .NET when 4.6.0 is installed

Tags: .net, clickonce, .net-4.6, .net-4.5.2, .net-4.6.2

I am using MS ClickOnce in VS2015 to deploy an application.  I have the prerequisite of .NET 4.5.2 checked under the Publish tab as the application requires .NET 4.5.2 minimum to use TLSv1.2 and I have it configured to use the vendor's website to download the installer.

Users that have .NET 4.6 installed are seeing the prompt to install 4.5.2, but when they go to install it the installers attempts to install 4.6.2.

1) Why are users with 4.6 even getting prompt to upgrade the framework?

2) Why when they click to install 4.5.2 it attempts to install 4.6.2?

Please let me know any thoughts or any additional details that are needed to help review this issue.

Comment: Crystal ball says that this wasn't triggered by your prerequisite but by the framework version you target in your project.  Project > Properties > Application tab > "Target framework" setting.  Using the prerequisite you actually tested is kinda important, 4.6 had pretty critical bugs that were fixed in 4.6.1.

Comment: My target framework under application tab is 4.5.2 and prereq is also 4.5.2.